# delete files from folder

Tags: c#

How do you remove files from a folder using ASP.Net with C# ?

Comment: Where are you trying to delete the files from?  If you want to delete files from a users machine you can't.  If you want to delete files from the web server you could use any of the suggested solutions below, but you will also need to ensure that the folder and all it's contents have the correct security permissions set.  Make sure that the asp.net user account has full control for the directory in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as the above answers, but lambda-fied, if that's your thing...

```
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(path), File.Delete);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
       File.Delete(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Path");
foreach (string file in files)
    File.Delete(file);
```